# Is "stream" hard-coded in Flask-SSE?

Tags: flask, flask-sse

I'm reading the documentation and have implemented a working Flask-SSE application. Documentation referenced here: https://flask-sse.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html

It notes to set up a route for "sse.stream" and "/stream".

Is that hard-coded within the library, or is there a way to change that to "/api" for example? I did attempt to simply change them, but received error "Could not build url for endpoint 'see.api' with values blah. Did you mean 'sse.stream' instead?"

Found this on the documentation as well: https://flask-sse.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html

Looks like they did exactly what I tried, changing it to '/sse', but when I change mine to '/api', mine errors out.

Adding the code line I'm attempting to use:

```
app.register_blueprint(sse, url_prefix='/api')
```

Answer (score 0):

Got a response directly from David, the developer of the Flask-SSE library.

Here is how you are able to use any url you want:

```
from flask_sse import sse, ServerSentEventsBlueprint

sse = ServerSentEventsBlueprint('sse', 'sse')
sse.add_url_rule(rule="", endpoint="api", view_func=sse.stream)
app.register_blueprint(sse, url_prefix='/api')
```

Here I am changing the default "/stream" to "/api" and registering it as my blueprint.

Now, I'm able to use "{{ url_for(sse.api) }}" on my front-end in jinja.

Thanks again David!